# Access gmail account through cmd prompt in linux

Tags: linux

I want to login to Gmail through cmd prompt. Please provide solutions.

Comment: being a old linux user myself, i think "web" is a "gui" thing. gmail's mailbox is quite wonderful then many traditional fat mail client. I think taking advantage of the gui does not mean  cli is useless. both of it has its strengths and weaknesses. although if you use **mutt** then you can edit your mail's in vim/emacs, which is the only advantage that comes to my mind. and **mutt** tries to emulate a gui like environment. so it also knows a **mailboxes** are infact a gui thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `mutt` email client.

[tutorial](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_mutt_with_gmail_imap).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using link. you will have to tell it to use the simple version once you get to the webpage, but it works. I've done this myself. their is sup and mutt, but links is the easiest way to go.